# Android Preference Screen Layout

Tags: java, android, xml, preferencescreen

I have the following preference screen in my app

```
<PreferenceScreen
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<EditTextPreference
android:key="edittexvalue"
android:id="@+id/edittextvalue"
android:title="Title Here"
android:summary="Summary Here" 
android:defaultValue="Some Value"/>
<Preference
android:key="customPref"
android:title="Title Here"
android:summary="Summary Here"/>
</PreferenceScreen>
```

All of that works just fine however my app i have custom backgrounds and text colors/sizes but i can't figure out how to format the PreferenceScreen I assume you point this at another xml? but can't figure out the code i need and what changes should be made. The main concern is the background color the text is fine i guess but the background just doesn't match the rest of my app. So i'd like to set a custom background color lets say red for now (#ff0000)

I thank anyone that can help me with this problem

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can to apply a `theme` to it in your `manifest`, for example

```
<activity android:name=".Settings"
     android:theme="@style/YourStyle"/>
```

and in your `styles.xml` (if you dont have one, create it in the values folder)
you can modify whatever you need

For example

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<style name="YourStyle" parent="android:Theme.Light">
    <item name="android:listViewStyle">@style/Widget.ListView</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>

<style name="Widget" parent="android:Widget">
</style>

<style name="Widget.ListView">
    <item name="android:background">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:divider">@color/gray_division</item>
    <item name="android:dividerHeight">2dip</item>       
</style>
</resources>
```

I hope this helps

Comment: Didn't think about using a theme but worked perfectly thanks!