# Change layout for Preference screen

Tags: android

I have a Preference screen and also two `EditTextPreference`.

I want to change its background color and font and also to add an image in its background.

How can I do that?

Here it the code as shown below for the layout in XML:

```
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <PreferenceCategory 
        android:title="Login Information"
        android:key="first_category">
        <EditTextPreference
            android:key="@string/txtusername"
            android:title="@string/username" 
            android:summary="@string/userNameSummary" />
    </PreferenceCategory>

    <PreferenceCategory
        android:title="Device Information"
        android:key="Device">
        <EditTextPreference
            android:key="welcome_message"
            android:title="DeviceId"
            android:summary="This is your mobile device ID"
            android:shouldDisableView="true" />
    </PreferenceCategory>
</PreferenceScreen>
```

Comment: This question is similar and may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5572149/android-preference-screen-layout

Comment: but how can i add image in background

Comment: @saqibabbasi read my comment below *prolink007* 's answer!

Answer (score 2):

Actually it looks like you may be stuck using [styles](http://developer.android.com/design/style/index.html) and [themes](http://developer.android.com/design/style/themes.html) in the XML for preferences.

You can set it differently in code though. After you create the preference, you will need to access its view and set the desired changes.

- To change the **background image** use the following, where `...` is a drawable.

`getView().setBackgroundDrawable(...);`

- To change **background color** use the following, where `...` is a
  color.

`getView().setBackgroundColor(...);`

- To change the **font** use the following, where `...` is a font type.

`getView().setTypeFace(...);`

- To change **font color** use the following, where `...` is a color.

`getView().setTextColor(...);`

Comment: Did not know you can customize preference screens - TIL! +1 from me on that! But then again, its best to stick to familiar preference screen layouts a lá Menu > Settings to keep consistency.

Comment: i want to preference screen same as my other app screen.want to add background image and change font

Comment: in my java class which is extended from Preference Activity,do not get getview.setbackground

Comment: What i have in my answer should help you out.

Comment: `getView()` above is arbitrary. It will change depending on what type of `View` you are getting. If you are in a `PreferenceActivity` you may need to use `findViewById(...).setBackgroundDrawable(...)`. Where the `...` in `findViewById(...)` is the resource id of the `View` you are trying to change.