# android set divider padding for preference screen

Tags: android, android-preferences

I have PreferenceScreen contain many CheckBox , i customize it by refer it to custom layout as bellow :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
 <PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <CheckBoxPreference 
   android:summary="checkbox one" 
   android:key="key_one" 
   android:layout="@layout/mylayout"      
    /> 
  <CheckBoxPreference 
   android:summary="checkbox two"
   android:key="key_two" 
   android:layout="@layout/mylayout"      
    /> 
</PreferenceScreen>
```

**mylayout.xml:**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"    
  android:layout_width="match_parent" 
  android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
  android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"  
  android:gravity="center_vertical" 
  android:paddingRight="?android:attr/scrollbarSize">
<LinearLayout 
  android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
  android:layout_height="match_parent"  
  android:gravity="center" 
  android:minWidth="@dimen/preference_icon_minWidth" 
  android:orientation="horizontal">
<ImageView 
  android:id="@+android:id/icon" 
  android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
  android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
  android:layout_gravity="center" /> 
</LinearLayout>
<RelativeLayout 
  android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_marginLeft="16dip"
  android:layout_marginRight="8dip" 
  android:layout_marginTop="6dip" 
  android:layout_marginBottom="6dip" 
  android:layout_weight="1">
<TextView 
  android:id="@+android:id/title" 
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" 
  android:fadingEdge="horizontal" /> 
<TextView 
  android:id="@+android:id/summary" 
  android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
  android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
  android:layout_below="@android:id/title" 
  android:layout_alignLeft="@android:id/title"
  android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" 
  android:textColor="?android:attr/textColorSecondary" 
  android:maxLines="4" /> 
</RelativeLayout>
<LinearLayout 
  android:id="@+android:id/widget_frame" 
  android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
  android:layout_height="match_parent" 
  android:minWidth="@dimen/preference_widget_width" 
  android:gravity="center"
  android:orientation="vertical" /> 
</LinearLayout>
```

Every thing run fine also i customize divider between checkbox in prefs activity as :

```
 ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
    list.setDivider(new ColorDrawable(Color.RED)); // or some other color int
    list.setDividerHeight((5)); 
    list.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);
```

when i want to set padding to divider only as :

```
  list.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
```

it set padding to all view ,

HOW can i set padding to divider only without affect padding of all view .

any help will be appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**To allow preference divider padding**

**first** : add this line to your preference activity which lead to transparency of android default divider

```
list.setDivider(new ColorDrawable(0x00000000));
```

**second** : create folder named drawable in res , then create on it divider.xml which will be as below :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
 <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <solid android:color="#B22222" /> 
 </shape>
```

**third** :

add View to your mylayout.xml so it will be as below :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
android:gravity="center_vertical"
android:paddingRight="?android:attr/scrollbarSize">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:minWidth="@dimen/preference_icon_minWidth"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+android:id/icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        />
</LinearLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dip"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dip"
    android:layout_marginTop="6dip"
    android:layout_marginBottom="6dip"
    android:layout_weight="1">

    <TextView android:id="@+android:id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"            
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"           
        android:fadingEdge="horizontal" />

    <TextView android:id="@+android:id/summary"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@android:id/title"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@android:id/title"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:textColor="?android:attr/textColorSecondary"
        android:maxLines="4" />

    <View 
       android:id="@+id/divider" 
       android:background="@drawable/divider" 
       android:layout_width="match_parent" 
       android:layout_marginLeft="30dp" 
       android:layout_marginRight="30dp" 
       android:layout_height="5dp" 
       android:layout_below="@+android:id/summary"/> 

</RelativeLayout>

<!-- Preference should place its actual preference widget here. -->
<LinearLayout android:id="@+android:id/widget_frame"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:minWidth="@dimen/preference_widget_width"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical" />
```

the point here you add View bellow your texts and refer that view to divider shape in drawable res so finally you will get an custom divider which it can be customized as you need.

hope that help you .

the output will be as below:

[image]

Comment: Hi, i'm trying to remove the divider lines in my preference fragment. But i'm not getting how to call `ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);` I dont have view object in fragment

Answer (score 1):

You have to create your custom drawable-shape

**custom_divider.xml**

```
<shape android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="@color/grey" />
    <corners android:radius="2dp" />
</shape>
```

set this as divider for your ListView in xml

**activity_list.xml**

```
<ListView
    android:dividerHeight="2dp"
    android:divider="@drawable/custom_divider"
    ...
/>
```

Comment: i don't have listview , we call listview as android.R.id.list in activity to allow to customize divider in preference screen ,thanks

Answer (score 1):

You must create your own drawable resource for divider:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<inset xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:insetTop="5dp">

    <shape android:shape="rectangle">

         <solid android:color="#FF0000" />

         <size android:height="4dp" />

    </shape>

</inset>
```

In this case divider shape height is 4dp and top padding is 5dp, when you set divider height you must sum shape height + inset's.

```
ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
list.setDivider(new ColorDrawable(Color.RED)); // or some other color int
list.setDividerHeight((5)); //wrorng code
list.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);
```

To set divider height correctly for all dencity screens you must set it in dp's but for default number "5" interpreted in pixels(px).

```
final float scale = getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
int pixels = (int) (dps * scale + 0.5f);
```

For more information about shape and inset drawable resource use Android Documentation [Drawable resources](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html)

Answer (score 1):

You should try deriving a theme from android's default one, assigning it to your preference screen (although they say there's a bug on 2.x versions that prevents you from doing that unless you workaround as described [here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=4611)), and overriding the `android:dividerPadding` property of one of the styles.

I can't really tell you for sure which style that would be, you'll have to dig into it, here's android's [styles.xml](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/res/res/values/styles.xml) for reference and here's an example [how to override ListView appearance in a theme](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5572377/375929)