# how to hide the divider between preferences in fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment, preference, divider

I want to hide the divider between preferences in fragment.
The code is below:

1.SettingsActivity.java

```
public class SettingsActivity extends PreferenceActivity {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    SettingsFragment settingsFragement = new SettingsFragment();
    FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    transaction.add(android.R.id.content, settingsFragement, "settings");
    transaction.commitAllowingStateLoss();
}
```

2.SettingsFragment.java

```
public class SettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragment{
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.settings);
    }
}
```

3.settings.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <PreferenceCategory>
        <Preference 
             android:key="preference_a"
             android:title="preferenceA"/>
        <Preference 
             android:key="preference_b"
             android:title="preferenceB"/>
        <ListPreference 
             android:key="list_preference_c"
             android:title="list_preferenceC"/>
    </PreferenceCategory>
</PreferenceScreen>
```

There are system default dividers amoung the preferences.
I want to hide the dividers.

How to hide the dividers? Thanks a lot.

---

Thanks for everyone`s answer. But,the question is that I cannot get the listview from the activity and fragment.

```
ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
```

Comment: try as `lv.setDivider(new ColorDrawable(Color.WHITE));`

Comment: sorry,there is no listView.

Comment: as answered by @rana, extend your fregment from `PreferenceFragmentCompat` and change the underlying recyclerview.

Answer (score 20):

if you are using PreferenceFragmentCompat , it is using Recycle view so you have to use this code . This automatically hides the divider

```
@Nullable
@Override
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

   setDivider(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
   setDividerHeight(0);
}
```

Comment: Just put this in onViewCreated and it works just fine. This is the best solution.

Answer (score 10):

These solutions didn't work for me. Here's what I did in `PreferenceFragmentCompat`:

```
@Override
public void setDivider(Drawable divider) {
    super.setDivider(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
}

@Override
public void setDividerHeight(int height) {
    super.setDividerHeight(0);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Define custom preference theme without dividers in your `style.xml`:

```
<style name="PrefsTheme" parent="PreferenceThemeOverlay.v14.Material">
    <item name="android:divider">@null</item>
    <item name="android:dividerHeight">0dp</item>
</style>
```

and don't forget to use it in your main app theme which is also in `style.xml`:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- ... -->
    <item name="preferenceTheme">@style/PrefsTheme</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove your divider by style.

```
<style name="PreferenceFragment.Material">
    <item name="android:divider">@null</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score -1):

**First:** if used the listview in xml

set the `android:dividerHeight="0dp"` in listview in xml file ,

**second:**

```
ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
list.setDivider(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT)); // or some other color int
list.setDividerHeight((int) getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density);
```

Comment: sorry,I tried.but there is not android:dividerHeight in Preference and ListPreference.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: try this below link ,http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17983627/android-set-divider-padding-for-preference-screen

Comment: @Igor , initially the questions coding having the listview contents, so that i recommended,try to implement above my code in xml,