# How to remove the horizontal line in the bottom in PreferenceScreen?

Tags: android, preference, preferencescreen

I am getting one horizontal line in but there is not any horizontal line in the bottom ,I don't know where is wrong

```
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

       <PreferenceCategory >
           <PreferenceScreen 
              ...... />
       </PreferenceCategory>
       ......
    </PreferenceScreen>
```

[image]

Comment: have you set a divider line some were?

Comment: Have you checked this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17983627/android-set-divider-padding-for-preference-screen ?

Comment: no divider line in  Preference,i have checked it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is be created by system, we can not hide it,but it works well in android 6.0

Comment: wtf does this mean?

Answer (score 2):

Can remove by PreferenceCategory with no title on down the last item

```
<PreferenceCategory
    android:title="" />
```

Answer (score 1):

please try this.`

```
@Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        // remove dividers
        View rootView = getView();
        ListView list = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
        list.setDivider(null);

    }`
```